# last button of dynamic list not always firing click event with jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have a simple div that I dynamically append buttons to, now all the the button click events fire except for the last element in the list, which sometimes it does fire sometimes it doesn't. If I click on the left or right icon in the button it works just fine, if I click on the text or middle of the button sometimes it fires sometimes it doesn't.

```
<div id="btn-list"></div>
```

on page load after my dom is loaded I append a random number of buttons and I add the on click event listener to the buttons.

```
$( function () {
  for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    var btn = $(document.createElement('button'));
     btn.text(item['description']);
     btn.attr('id', i);
     $("#btn-list").append(btn);
  }

  $('#btn-list').on('click', 'button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    window.location.replace('blah.html');
  });
}
```

I'm using jQuery 2.0.

Comment: Should always work...see any errors in the console? Could you make a fiddle to re-produce the problem?

Comment: sorry yes i fixed the typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without extra code, this snippet shouldn't fail. Have in mind that a reference to the last button added is kept in `btn`, thus if at some other part of the code the element or its events are modified it will alter the expected behavior.

Have you added some debug output to confirm the click event is not fired? http://jsfiddle.net/AstDerek/gKJNe/

```
$('#btn-list').on('click', 'button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('blah.html');
})
```

Added a simple test, it doesn't fail at the browser I tested, maybe its limited to your browser? http://jsfiddle.net/AstDerek/gKJNe/1/

Now, what happens if you encapsulate the button creation into its own function?

```
function create_button (index,properties) {
    var btn = $(document.createElement('button'));

    btn.text(properties.description);
    btn.attr('id',index);
    $("#btn-list").append(btn);

    return btn;
}

for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    create_button(i,arr[i]);
}
```

Finally, just as a workaround, why not add a hidden button as last step?

```
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    create_button(i,arr[i]);
}

create_button(-1,{description:''}).hide();
```

Comment: yes I even added an alert and works for all the buttons except the last one which sometimes it alerts sometimes not.

Comment: could CSS also affect the events? like webkit-transition?

Comment: I don't think so, but browser/machine performance may affect the events

Comment: cause its a phonegap app running on iOS

Comment: yeah sorry i forgot to say that i'm already encapsulating the button creation in a function named createTaskElement, I tried with the dummy button and that didn't work either. For some reason, if I change my event to touchstart or touchend it works everytime, but that causes problems with my scrolling, because if I scroll and touch a button it redirects right away instead continuing scrolling.

Comment: Sounds like a phonegap bug to me

Comment: I think you're right, its so frustrating! lol thanks alot @Ast Derek

Comment: Wow I noticed that the only time my button doesn't fire the click event is when I click on the text part of the button on the last element in my scrollable div, if i click anywhere around the text part it works all the time.